# How to add mnemonic character to a regular button in Flex? (Need that for shortcuts)

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

How to add mnemonic character to a regular button in Flex? Show me some examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an extended button component, that can help you deal with the task:

```
package test
{
import mx.controls.Button;
import flash.text.TextFormat;

public class ShortcutButton extends Button
{
    private static const underlineTF:TextFormat = new TextFormat(null, null, null, null, null, true);

    public function ShortcutButton()
    {
        super();
    }

    protected var shortcutPosition:int = -1;

    override public function set label(value:String):void
    {
        shortcutPosition = value.indexOf("~");
        if (shortcutPosition >= 0)
            value = value.substring(0, shortcutPosition) + value.substring(shortcutPosition + 1);
        super.label = value;
    }

    override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void
    {
        super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
        if (shortcutPosition > -1 && shortcutPosition < textField.text.length - 1)
            textField.setTextFormat(underlineTF, shortcutPosition, shortcutPosition+1);
    }
}
}
```

Just place "~" symbol before the symbol you want to underline to show it's a shortcut mnemonic character.

Example (you'll have to add `xmlns:test="test.*"` to the container component):

```
<test:ShortcutButton label="~Update" />
```

Comment: Great! :-) Thanks a lot.

One thing, "if (shortcutPosition == 0)" case should be also considered.

Answer (score 2):

1st Solution:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">

Just set the encoding value of the mxml file and you can type the 
special character right in.  ISO-8859-1 encoding type works for me with 
the © symbol.

2nd Solution:

Let's Example, The © escape sequence is only defined for HTML, and not XML. 
According to the W3C XML 1.0 recommendation, only a handful of such 
mnemonic escape sequences are defined.  However, you can include other 
characters using numeric character references by specifying their 
Unicode code points.

See:  http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#syntax

**For instance, the copyright symbol can be expressed as either (without 
the double quotes): "©" or "&xA9;" (hexadecimal).**  This will work 
provided the font that you're using has the glyphs for the code point 
that you're referencing (as Unicode defines characters and symbols from 
  a very wide assortment of languages, many of which will not exist in 
all fonts.

For a list of all the Unicode characters and their code points, you can 
consult the Unicode code charts available here:

http://www.unicode.org/charts/

You can also lists online giving the code points for some of the more 
common symbols, and most operating systems now come with a character or 
symbol picker (e.g. Microsoft Windows' character map utility) that'll 
oftentimes list the characters' code points as well.

Answer (score 1):

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=accessible_7.html

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. How is it related to mnemonic shortcuts?